# Вывод цикла mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста есть такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столбец `pod` - кому подчиняется.
Как вывести циклом всех подчиненных?
Вот такой код выводит только иерархию из двух строк.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM dolzhnosti LIMIT 1");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<div>".$row['name']."</div>";
   $stmt2 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM dolzhnosti WHERE pod='".$row['id']."'");
while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()) {
    echo "  <div style='margin-left:50px;'>".$row2['name']."</div>";
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Не делайте вложенные запросы (в цикле), получите все данные сразу, а потом в цикле проверяйте, кто кому подчиняется. 2. Не мешайте код с версткой.

Comment: Указывайте точную версию MySQL.

Comment: @Akina указываю 5.1.73

Comment: Ёооо... ему ж 6 лет уже... в этой версии для получения всех потомков одним запросом только хранимую процедуру писать. Устроит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, pod FROM dolzhnosti";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);




if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $id = '';
    $margin = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row['pod'] == 0) {
            echo "<div>".$row['name']."</div>";
        }

        if($row["id"] != $id) {
            if($row["pod"] == $id) {
               $margin += 50;
               echo "<div style='margin-left:".$margin."px;'>".$row['name']."</div>";
            }

        }
        $id = $row["id"];

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```